# resize child content of element host with form resize

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I am completely new to WPF and have to do a bit of work on it for my job. I have a form which contains 3 element hosts each with their own child controls. I need the child controls to resize with the form so they grow and shrink when the form does.

Only the element hosts themselves seem to have the anchor property which is what I understand I need to manipulate to achieve this. How can I get the child controls to resize as well as the element hosts or am I doing this completely wrong?
Any help would be great.

I've tested with a standard text box control, and setting the Anchor property of that to Top, Left, Bottom works fine. I don't understand why it doesn't work for the element host content

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyControls.ucEventViewerOptions"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/,arkup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        d:DesignHeight="297" d:DesignWidth="128" Loaded="UserControl_Loaded">
    <Grid Width="96" Height="288">
        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="288" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="dgEventViewerOptions" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="96" SelectionChanged="dgEventViewOptions_SelectionChanged" />
    </Grid>
 </UserControl>
```

Comment: Please post a non-working XAML sample so we can point out what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WPF, this type of behavior is generally caused by the `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` properties. Ommitting these properties will set them to their default value `"Stretch"` and allows controls to resize in relation to their parent containers. This is only possible when the controls are not assigned with fixed sizes, though.

In your case, you may simply ommit these properties:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyControls.ucEventViewerOptions"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/,arkup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        d:DesignHeight="297" d:DesignWidth="128" Loaded="UserControl_Loaded">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="dgEventViewerOptions" SelectionChanged="dgEventViewOptions_SelectionChanged" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Unless you wish them to have a fixed height or width, of course.

Answer (score 1):

If you want items to resize depending on parent elements size, you have to keep in mind that controls are implicitly inheriting parents' stretching behavior when size *is not set explicitly*. So to fix your problem, you need to remove setting `Width` and `Height` explicitly:

```
<Grid>
   <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="dgEventViewerOptions" SelectionChanged="dgEventViewOptions_SelectionChanged" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, all sorted now